# Multiplying all columns in a pandas data frame by each other

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame with 30 columns and about 250k rows, I want to expand this to include the multiplication of all variables by each other.

At the moment I'm doing the following, and it works but it's extremely slow. Are there any better ways to achieve the same result?

```
import itertools
for p in itertools.combinations(range(1,30),2): #First column is an id, so not included
    newColName = df.columns[p[0]] + '*' + df.columns[p[1]] #Create the name of the column
    df[newColName] = df[[p[0]]].values * df[[p[1]]].values
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fundamentally very similar to your code, but I got a significant speedup rewriting your code as below.

```
In [185]: from string import ascii_lowercase

In [186]: df_base = pd.DataFrame({l:range(250000) for l in ascii_lowercase})

In [173]: %%time
     ...: df = df_base.copy()
     ...: for pair in combinations(df.columns, 2):
     ...:     new_col = '*'.join(pair)
     ...:     df[new_col] = df[pair[0]] * df[pair[1]]
Wall time: 10.5 s
```

I think the main difference comes from doing multiplication as `df[a] * d[b]`, rather than `df[[a]] * df[[b]]`  Here's some code showing an example difference in speed.

```
In [199]: %timeit df['a'] * df['b']
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.88 ms per loop

In [200]: %timeit df[['a']] * df[['b']]
1 loops, best of 3: 21.3 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `numpy.repeat` and `numpy.tile`, and then multiply the two element-wise:

```
>>> df
    A    B
0 -41   55
1 -17  -53
2 -33 -130
>>> np.repeat(df.values, 2, axis=1)
array([[ -41.,  -41.,   55.,   55.],
       [ -17.,  -17.,  -53.,  -53.],
       [ -33.,  -33., -130., -130.]])
>>> np.tile(df.values, 2)
array([[ -41.,   55.,  -41.,   55.],
       [ -17.,  -53.,  -17.,  -53.],
       [ -33., -130.,  -33., -130.]])
```

the columns' names map similarly:

```
>>> [x+y for x, y in zip(np.repeat(df.columns, 2), np.tile(df.columns, 2))]
['AA', 'AB', 'BA', 'BB']
```